# Compressing UTF8 into UTF16, decompression not working

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, compression, utf-16

Because JavaScript stores strings in `localStorage` as UTF-16 but most of my data lies within the UTF-8 range, I am attempting to compress it into UTF-16 before storing it.

I found an algorithm online for doing the compression; [Text re-encoding for optimising storage capacity in the browser](http://labs.ft.com/2012/06/text-re-encoding-for-optimising-storage-capacity-in-the-browser/), I used the third one listed on the webpage. Unfortunately they did not supply one to decompress the data.

It works by base64 encoding my data, because base64 can be described reliably with 6 bits (where `'A' = 1` and `'/' = 63`) and UTF-16 with 16 bits, I can pack multiple base64 characters into each UTF-16 character.

For example, the base64 snippet `R2lIdaXh` can be broken into 6 bit bytes like so:

```
R      2      l      I      d      a      X      h
17     54     37     8      29     26     23     33
010001 110110 100101 001000 011101 011010 010111 100001
```

Then encoded as UTF16 via concatenation like so:

```
䝩               䡵                ꗡ
18281            18549            42465
0100011101101001 0100100001110101 1010010111100001
```

Because `16 % 6 = 4` some base64 characters are shared between multiple UTF16 characters.

The algorithm used for compression is this:

```
/*
 * Converts a string to base64 then re-encodes it as UTF-16
 *
 * @param {string} string The string to be re-encoded
 * @return {string}
 */
function compress(string) {
  var output = '';
  var encoded = base64.encode(string);
  var bits = 16;
  var charCode = 0;
  var rem = 0;
  var len = encoded.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var char = encoded[i];
    if (bits > 6) {
      /* Enough bits left to store this byte */
      bits -= 6;
      /* Shift the bits left into their position and sum them to the total */
      charCode += base64.indices[char] << bits;
    } else {
      /* This byte will overflow */
      rem = 6 - bits;
      charCode += base64.indices[char] >> rem;
      output += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
      charCode = (base64.indices[char] % rem) << (16 - rem);
      bits = 16 - rem;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

I then use the following function for decompression:

```
/*
 * Reverses the compress function.
 * Converts a UTF-16 string to 6-bit character codes, maps them to base64 then decodes the base64.
 *
 * @param {string} string The string to be re-encoded
 * @return {string}
 */
function decompress(string) {
  var output = '';
  var byte = 0;
  var rem = 0;
  var bits = 0;
  var charCode = 0;
  var len = string.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bits += 16;
    byte += string.charCodeAt(i);
    while (bits >= 6) {
      bits -= 6;
      /* Retrieve the left-most 6 relevant bits from the byte */
      charCode = byte >> bits;
      /* Map the number to base64 */
      output += base64.chars[charCode];
      /* Remove the retrieved bits from the byte */
      byte -= charCode << bits;
    }
    if (bits !== 0) {
      /* Push the remaining bits to the left of the next byte */
      byte = byte << 16;
    }
  }
  return base64.decode(output);
}
```

Whilst this approach comes close their are some errors, e.g.,

```
var test = 'Gee whiz! How do you do? Would you like some tea?';
var compressed = compress(test);
var decompressed = decompress(compressed);
console.log('Input:', test);
console.log('Compressed:', compressed);
console.log('Decompressed:', decompressed);
```

Results in the following output:

```
Input:       Gee whiz! How do you do? Would you like some tea?
Compressed:  䝥攠㝨楺℠࡯眠摯⁹潵⁤⼿⁗潵Ɽ⁹潵⁬楫攠㍯浥⁴╡㼐
Decompresed: Gee 7hiz! ow do you d/? Wou,d you like 3ome t%a?
```

If we compare the base64 input and output we get the following:

```
Input:  R2VlIHdoaXohIEhvdyBkbyB5b3UgZG8/IFdvdWxkIHlvdSBsaWtlIHNvbWUgdGVhPw==
Output: R2VlIDdoaXohIAhvdyBkbyB5b3UgZC8/IFdvdSxkIHlvdSBsaWtlIDNvbWUgdCVhPx
Errors:      6       14              30      38              54      62  66
```

I'm starting to think that the error could be in the `compress` function but I'm not sure, can anyone see why the decompressed data doesn't match?

Comment: Conversion between different UTF has nothing to do with compression. BTW: The linked article promulgates the fallac that counting characters in UTF-16 is any cheaper than in UTF-8...

Comment: @Deduplicator `localStorage` saves as UTF-16, therefore two characters that exist in the UTF-8 space will be saved as two UTF-16 characters and get padded. Here I concatenate them to become UTF-16 thus only saving one UTF-16 character per two UTF-8 characters. Hence compression once saved to disk.

Comment: You want re-coding or re-encoding. Also, as the differences are actually crucial for you, consider using the precise terms code-unit and code-point (you are not interested in logicl characters at all), instead of the sloppily used and ambiguously defined character. That would clean up your question immensely, and would probably also help your understanding of what really happens. As an example, UTF-8 is less restricted than UTF-16, not the other way around (especially if one disregards validity).

Comment: @Deduplicator See the comments in my code. `code-unit` and `code-point` is just needless pedantry and doesn't change what my question is asking. I'm more interested in bitwise math than anything. This function results in less data being stored to describe the same information, hence it is compression in this sense.

Comment: Unicode is not that simple. Deduplicator actually points out valid problems with the whole idea - just clumping characters together doesn't guarantee they'll be spit out the same on the other side, because a lot of things can change as part of the conversion - for example, there are special sequences that might be removed altogether, not to mention that you're going to encounter a lot of issues with normalization. In effect, you're trying to serialize a byte array into UTF-16 and back - that is not possible, because there are byte sequences that simply can't be represented in UTF-16 reliably.

Comment: And the article you're referencing makes several basic mistakes about how Unicode in general and UTF-16 specifically works - most importantly, completely ignoring surrogate pairs, normalization, padding... And by using Base-64, you've basically managed to get what, 30% reduction in size? So in the end, you're doing a lot of work to make sure you don't support non-ASCII characters and save 30%? Wouldn't it be better to think of other ways to save space than encoding?

Comment: @Luaan It's roughly 49% reduction in size according to my tests, depending on how much padding is required. Base64 results in larger strings but it also can be described in 6 instead of 8 bits, so more fit in. Also JavaScript strings are all UTF-16 anyway... I don't see an issue here when all I am using is the bit data and not what the UTF-16 value actually is.

Comment: @Luaan Only `n >= 2^16` need to be encoded as surrogate pairs, so that is not an issue as `2^16 - 1` is my upper bound. The base64 conversion  ensures all my characters are in the safe range.

Comment: The problem is from the opposite side - some of the things you are encoding may be *interpreted* as surrogate pairs, for example. Since you're slapping bytes together, you're *not* doing a safe operation at all, even though all your individual characters are 6-bit. The problem is that you're not using the bit data at all, because there's a lot of conversions between bits, unicode and back. At any of those points, your data can become mangled. In the end, it really isn't any different from trying to encode random bytes as fake-UTF-16 and expecting to get the original bytes back again.

Answer (score 0):

[LZString](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) compresses characters exclusively for localStorage and I highly recommend its use for this case. **My code below is designed for learning and it works, but don't use it.**

Anyway, you can learn a little more about compression by reading my answer. My code was made only for the client side and for storage in localStorage.

Your code uses `btoa` but I found it very difficult to work with it because many characters used on a daily basis do not work and we received an error. I chose to use the `encodeURIComponent` instead and it worked.

The [only problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description) occurs in characters with code between 55296 and 57343 where we received an error too, but I got around this sequence in the code and did some tests. It works very well with accentuation and other special characters and the output is identical to the input as it should be.

It generates compression in several common texts because A-Z characters are unified into a single character. However, in some types of characters the `encodeURIComponent` transforms them into a sequence and sometimes the compression does not exist and the output has more characters than the input.

But in general almost all cases the compression is about 30%. That is, I completed my goal because it really does compression, but I will use LZString because it is so much superior and can store a lot more information. **My code seems to be faster, but they are milliseconds and not worth using!**

```
// compress-utf8.js v1
function compressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(text) {
    let output = '';
    try{
        text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    }catch(e){
        /*
        this try is practically optional because this error is very rare:
        the encodeURI cannot convert characters with codes between 55296 and 57343
        try it yourself: encodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode(55296))
        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description
        */
        let newText = '';
        let textLength = text.length;
        for(let i = 0; i < textLength; i++){
            let code = text.charCodeAt(i);
            if( code >= 55296 && code <= 57343 ){
                newText += String.fromCharCode(0, 1, 3) + code;
                continue;
            };
            newText += text[i];
        };
        text = encodeURIComponent(newText);
    };
    text += text.length % 2 ? String.fromCharCode(0) : ''; // if is odd
    let textLength = text.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < textLength; i += 2) {
        let code = text.charCodeAt(i) * 256 + text.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        output += String.fromCharCode(code);
    };
    return output;
};

function decompressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(text) {
    let output = '',
        textLength = text.length,
        lastCharacter = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
        let code = text.charCodeAt(i),
            firstCharacter = Math.floor(code / 256);
        lastCharacter = code % 256;
        output += String.fromCharCode(firstCharacter, lastCharacter);
    };
    output = lastCharacter !== 0 ? output : output.substring(0, output.length - 1);
    output = decodeURIComponent(output);
    // the regexp and if block are only necessary if try block exist in compress function
    let regexp = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(0, 1, 3) + '\\d{5}', 'g');
    if(output.match(regexp)){
        output = output.replace(regexp, function(match){
            return String.fromCharCode(match.substring(3,7));
        });
    };
    return output;
};
```

In this example we can see that the accent works and that in this case because there are many special characters, there is an increase in the number of characters

```
let input = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÇĆĈḈçćĉḉÐðÈÉÊËèéêëǴĜǵĝĤĥÌÍÎÏìíîïĴĵḰḱĹĺḾḿÑǸŃñǹńÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöṔṕŔŕŠŜŚšŝś    ÙÚÛÜùúûüṼṽẂẀŴẃẁŵÝŸỲỸŶýÿỳỹŷŽẐŹžẑź&';
let compressed = compressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(input);
let decompressed = decompressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(compressed);
console.log(compressed);
console.log(decompressed);
console.log(input === decompressed);
console.log( input.length, compressed.length );
```

In this example a simple text and here the compression works as well as in most cases

```
let input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dignissim efficitur gravida. Sed vitae augue dolor. Nulla semper, dolor eu volutpat ultricies, diam odio convallis velit, lobortis accumsan urna magna quis magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas ultricies turpis eget nisi ultricies feugiat. Pellentesque faucibus, turpis in ornare cursus, orci leo aliquet ligula, sit amet faucibus dui diam egestas arcu. Integer rhoncus tortor nec mauris feugiat efficitur. Nam viverra justo quis elementum semper. Nullam nec purus gravida, pretium risus eget, vulputate dolor. Nullam porta aliquet odio, nec commodo enim. Curabitur ultrices luctus condimentum. Aliquam tristique congue ipsum, ac semper odio venenatis id.';
let compressed = compressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(input);
let decompressed = decompressUtf8InnerOfUtf16(compressed);
console.log(compressed);
console.log(decompressed);
console.log(input === decompressed);
console.log( input.length, compressed.length );
```

I partially used the code explained in that [article](https://labs.ft.com/2012/06/text-re-encoding-for-optimising-storage-capacity-in-the-browser/).